# pass if IF statement arguments from HTML form in frontend?

Tags: php, function, user-input

I want users to be able to execute if statement in PHP by providing values in the HTML Currently i am stuck here how can i process `$expression` if user enters in form e.g. "**2 + 3 = 5**"?

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
   Evaluate <input type="text" required="required" name="expression" /><br />
   True <input type="text" required="required" name="returnOnTrue" /><br />
   False <input type="text" required="required" name="returnOnFalse" /><br />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Run" />
</form>
```

Then in PHP i have something like

```
function if_statement($expression, $true, $false) {

    try {

        if (    !empty($expression)
             && !empty($true) && ctype_digit($true)
             && !empty($false) && ctype_digit($false)
        ) {

            if ($expression) {
                return $true;
            } else {
                return $false;
            }

        }

        return;   

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return;
    }

}

$expression = $POST["expression"];
$onTrue     = $POST["returnOnTrue"];
$onFalse    = $POST["returnOnFalse"];

echo call_user_func_array("if_statement", array($expression, $onTrue, $onFalse));
```

Is there other more secure way to make IF statement take user input to avoid injection and/or fatal errors.

Comment: you can control the length of the "expression"

Comment: As Hann mentioned you will need to validate your input, key word there ;)

Comment: Can you go in more details on how i would validate it, this is pretty much myquestion. Should i use variable variables, regex etc?

Comment: OP, Please do yourself a favor and not make this code on a live server. Trying to use functionality like this in a webpage (even if you wanted it more secure) is an open invitation to hackers. You are better off looking up source codes to calculators, at least then hackers would only be limited to pressing buttons which gives you more control of the input they provide.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you would need to parse the input character by character to determine what they are checking.  There wouldn't really be a security issue if not using eval() or database interaction.  If always expecting the same type of simple expression you could use regex to get the parts instead of parsing.  If you want to make sure the parts are digits, you can just cast to an integer like

```
$expression = (int)$_POST['expression'];
```

By the way if doing if ($expression), it will should always return true unless the input is empty, or a number less than one (0, 0.5, -7).  So some parsing or regex would be needed.

Comment: Part of the question was how to avoid if ($expression) showing true all the time and rather evaluate it. I am thinking i should evaluate $expression outside if and just give if statement a result of that expression i think this is safer.

I also want allow to allow users to use expressions like this `<input type="text" name="expression" value="stristr("hello word", "hello")" />` not just numeric.

Comment: To allow more instructions such as stristr, you would need to either use eval($expression) (extremely unsafe), or parse the input for functions, which shouldn't be to hard if there are not to many of them.